# How to compare the current date with past 60 days using shell script

Tags: shell

```
start_time=`sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/' <<< "$line"`
start_time_sec=`date -d "$start_time" +%s`
now=`date +%s`
pass_time=`$now - $start_time_sec`
if [ $pass_time <=86400*60 ]
then
initial_time= $start_time
initial_time_sec=`date -d "$initial_time" +%s`
break
```

fi
   /*Here I have tried with date comparison with seconds, But I want in terms of days*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_time=`echo $line | sed -e 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`
start_time_sec=`date -d "$start_time" +%s`
now=`date +%s`
pass_time=`expr $now - $start_time_sec`
limit_time=$((60 * 60 * 24 * 60))
if [[ $pass_time -le $limit_time ]]; then                                                                                                                                                                         
  echo "in 60 days"
fi
```

update:
or your idea:

```
start_time_date=`date -d "$start_time" +%s`
past_date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "-60 day"`
if [[ $past_date -le $start_time_date ]]; then
    echo 'in 60 days'
fi
```

Comment: @user3165241 `expr` is a shell command which evaluates expressions.:)

Comment: @user3165241 you can also use `pass_time=$((now-start_time_sec))`

Comment: Thanks, I have used   past_date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "-60 day"`

Comment: then how to compare the two dates without converting into seconds?

Comment: you can use `if [[ $post_data -le $xx ]]` to compare directly :).

Comment: Hi I am getting error like "Syntax error: redirection unexpected" in following line:  start_time=`sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/' <<< "$line"`

Comment: You can use ``echo $line | sed -e 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'``

Answer (score 1):

ISO dates (YYYY-MM-DD) can be compared like strings:

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d
2014-01-07
$ date +%Y-%m-%d -d '-60 days'
2013-11-08
$ [[ "$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '-60 days')" < "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" ]]
$ echo $?
0
```